# Prestashop custom hooks

Tags: hook, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to include several blocks of contents in homepage.
This content must the from some modules, such as testimonials, blog and last viewed product.

How can I hook this modules in homepage?

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach your code to the displayHome hook.

Here's the official documentation regarding this:

http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Managing+Hooks